# What should be done on Datta Jayanti?

Tags: dattatreya

Datta (Dattatreya) Jayanti falls on Decmber 13th this year.

Can you tell me how should this day be observed? What rituals or prayers should be done on this day?

Comment: Not sure about rituals but here are two stotrams dedicated to Lord Dattatreya.You can read them:1)Dattatreya Stotram-http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Dattatreya_stotram 2)Sri Datta Sharanashtakam-http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Sri_Datta_Sharanashtakam